# Is there any benefit to Thread.sleep() in an infinite loop?

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a construct wherein a variable is constantly updated based on how long the application has been open.

```
while (playTime < allowedTime) {
    endTimeSec = (int) (System.currentTimeMillis() / MILLISECONDS);
    playTime = endTimeSec - startTime;
}
```

This check is constantly running on a Thread separate from where my actual app is. My question is, since I'm basically concerned with accuracy down to the second, would there be any benefit to having `Thread.sleep(1000)` every time the loop is iterated?

Comment: Thread.sleep doesn't consume CPU cycles

Comment: You'll get drift if you do it that way. Better to schedule wakeup for exactly when the second boundary ticks over, not to just sleep for a second.

Comment: ...but either way, yah, you don't want to be constantly looping uselessly; that's just silly.

Comment: shouldn't you just use a timer or something to get notified when the allowedTime is elapsed?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/sleep.html

Comment: That might be better, the construct I have here handles pauses much more gracefully though (this isn't all of the code)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, there is a benefit to `Thread.sleep(1000);` in this case.  That will put your `Thread` to sleep for a second, so it doesn't consume CPU resources during this time.

It's as if you are taking your kids on vacation on a long car ride.  Instead of the kids asking "Are we there yet?" once every microsecond, they will ask once every second.  That's *much* better.